# iReport CSV preview - where does the CSV get saved?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm running iReport on ubuntu. When I choose the CSV preview from the Build menu and choose Build -> execute (with active connection) a message is displayed in the console saying "Exporting Report". But nothing happens afterwards. Where does the CSV file get saved?

PS:- When choosing JRViewer preview things work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files were in the **bin** directory of the root iReport directory.